# How to split a byte into its upper and lower halves

Tags: python, file, byte

I am writing a Python program where I process a file byte-by-byte, and I am trying to write a function that splits a byte into its upper and lower halves. To elaborate, let's say I want to run this function on the byte with the decimal value `18` and the hexadecimal value `12`. I would want it to be split into two bytes with values of `1` and `2`.

Here is a function I wrote to do this:

```
# split byte into upper and lower halves 
def splitByte(b): 
   lowerMask = b'\x0F' 
   lowerHalf = bytes(b & lowerMask[0])[0] 
   upperMask = b'\xF0' 
   upperHalf = bytes(b & upperMask[0])[0] 
   upperHalf = upperHalf >> 4 
   return [upperHalf,lowerHalf]
```

Here is where I am calling the function:

```
info = stream.read(1)
result = splitByte(info[0])
print(result)
```

However, when I run a file with just the above code and the function, the following occurs:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
result = splitByte(info[0])
  File "<home folder>/byteops.py", line 21, in splitByte
    lowerHalf = bytes(b & lowerMask[0])[0]
IndexError: index out of range
```

Not only is the function returning `0` for both values, but it errors out on some inputs, with an 'index out of range' error. For context, here is the file I'm reading from, as viewed in a hex editor:

```
00000000: 4C 49 54 35 30 0A 09 09 02 01
```

I am running Manjaro Linux with Python 3.7.1. How should I fix my `splitByte` function, or is there a library function that does it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that converting from `int` to `bytes`.  `bytes(2)` is a request for a bytearray of two zeros.  You can simply use the int manipulations you already know:

```
# split byte into upper and lower halves 
def splitByte(b): 
   lowerHalf = b & 15
   upperHalf = (b >> 4) & 15
   return [upperHalf,lowerHalf]

result = splitByte(18)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

I left this as integers, since your original program needed only the byte division, not a `bytearray`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to do that. You can use the `ord` function to convert a single character to its ASCII value (in base 10). Then, you use the `hex` function to convert this value into an hexadecimal value (in string). You can now easily access to the upper and lower part of your value.

Here is an example:

```
val = 'a'
print(hex(ord(val))[2]) # 6
print(hex(ord(val))[3]) # 1
```

You get `6` and `1` because hexadecimal value of `a` is 0x61.

Now, if you directly get the decimal value of each character of your source file, you can get rid of the `ord` function:

```
val = 97
print(hex(val)[2]) # 6
print(hex(val)[3]) # 1
```